# Локализация и перевод приложения на react-native

Tags: react-native, localstorage, locale

Вопрос по структуре приложения и как такая функционалость достигается.

#### Что необходимо:

Сделать динамическое добавление новых переводов без пересборки и нового релиза. То есть на данный момент переводы жестко зашиваются в папку `src` и при изменении/добавлении есть необходимость пересборки всего приложения. Приложение с бэком общается только через запросы API.

#### Какие мысли приходят:

Можно получать данные о новых языках/обновлениях через запросы к апи, хранить это в `localStorage` и забирать значения для переменных либо из дефолтного состояния, либо из `localStorage`. Данный подход кажется громоздким и не производительным в том смысле, что реализация мультиязычности через `i18next` кажется недосягаемой и как бы выразиться:"не корректной".

#### Собственно вопрос:

Как такое реализовать с меньшими потерями сейчам и  в дальнейшем обслуживании

Comment: А чем вам вариант с API не нравится? В сборке пусть лежит дефолтный язык, вынесенный в отдельную "переменную"-справочник. При смене языка запрашиваете локализацию(допустим это для бэка обычный JSON файл в какой то папке или записи в БД, откуда динамически этот справочник формируется). Локализация приходит клиенту, справочник перезаписывается и ререндер приложения уже на новом языке. Можно сохранять справочник локально, только надо периодически проверять "версию" перевода и если она изменилась на сервере, перезапрашивать.

Comment: @SwaD вы хотите сказать, что я на правильном пути? И в такой реализации нет ничего необычного и это не подпадает под опредение "изобретать велосипед"?

Comment: Я не знаю всех стандартов, но я бы сделал так. Причем сами переводы положил бы в БД, что бы менять данные в любой момент и не зависить от релизов. А бэк заставил бы раз в N времени проверять обновления и сохранять в кэш справочники для быстрой отдачи клиенту. Если взаимодействие по сокету, то можно еще и броад кастом в клиентов обновленным справочником пульнуться. Я на своем проекте ровно так и делаю. Все справочники в БД(от системных до пользовательских), в релизе только логигика. Может кто другой еще другие варианты подскажет